# comparing a unicode type and str type date in python

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to compare a date received from a date type HTML input element and the current date.

This is my Python code.

```
deadline = request.POST.get('deadline', '')
    today = datetime.date.today().strftime("%B %d, %Y")
    print type(deadline)
    print type(today)
    if deadline > today:
        task_obj = Task(user=request.user, name=name, deadline=deadline)
        task_obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('tasks'))
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Deadline cannot be before current date.')
```

`print type(deadline)` outputs `<type 'unicode'>` while `print type(today)` outputs `<type 'str'>`. How do I compare these 2 in Python?

Comment: FYI `'January 01, 2014' < 'August 01, 2014'` is `False`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2, provided the unicode string doesn't contain anything other that ASCII codepoints, you can compare them directly:

```
if deadline == today:
```

and Python will implicitly encode the unicode string. Since your dates are not ISO8601 formatted you cannot do anything but test for equality this way; you cannot test if one is greater or smaller than the other, as you are comparing strings by *lexicographical sorting order* instead!

You really need to parse the HTML unicode value to a `datetime` object and compared that instead:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
deadline = datetime.datetime.strptime(deadline, "%B %d, %Y").date()
if deadline > today:
```

Now you are comparing `datetime.date()` objects, which actually let you test relative ordering by date.

Comment: This gives the error `type object 'datetime.date' has no attribute 'strptime'`

Comment: @YinYang: crumbs, I keep forgetting `date` has no such method. Corrected. Mea culpa!

Comment: Now I get the error `time data '2014-03-31' does not match format '%B %d, %Y'`

Comment: @YinYang: Why didn't you tell us about what format your HTML dates were in then? Why did you try to format `today` to a totally different format?

Comment: @YinYang: Use `%Y-%m-%d` to parse ISO-formatted dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
if deadline==today:
    ...
```